# How to break ob_start() and continue after some tags

Tags: php, caching, ob-start

I want to build a cache system for a e-commerce platform.

I've choosed to use `ob_start('callback')` and `ob_end_flush()` at the end of the page.

I will verify if there is any `.cache` file created for the visited url and if there is a file I will print its content out.

My problem is that I want to keep the shopping cart live so I don't want to cache it. How can I achieve that?

```
<?php

    function my_cache_function($content) {
        return $content;
    }

    ob_start('my_cache_function');

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
     test
     <?php
         //some ob_break() ?
     ?>
     <div id="shopping-cart">
         this should be the content I do not want to cache it
     </div>
     <?php
         // ob_continue() ?
     ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
     ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do that, the problem is that content will output BEFORE any HTML placed before. What you may want is to save that content in some variable, then use a placeholder in your cache "template" file, like %SHOPPING-CART%

You can therefore replace it with a str_replace with the real non-cached content.

Comment: The shopping cart will be available even if the user is not logged in. When the user is logged in there will be no cache so the only item I do not want to cache is the shopping cart which will be visible on every page. I'm sure your solution will work so thank you for your answer. I don't understand why I didn't think at this until now :))

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<?php

    function my_cache_function($content) {
        return $content;
    }
    $output = "";
    ob_start('my_cache_function');

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
     test
     <?php
         $output .= ob_get_clean();
     ?>
     <div id="shopping-cart">
         this should be the content I do not want to cache it
     </div>
     <?php
         ob_start();
     ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
         $output .= ob_get_clean();
         echo $output;
?>
```

Even though that doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Zulakis solution goes all the way... what about this alteration?

```
<?php
$pleaseCache=true;
function my_cache_function($content) {
    if($pleaseCache)
    {
        /// do your caching
    }
    return $content;
}
$output = "";
ob_start('my_cache_function');

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
     test
     <?php
         $output .= ob_get_clean();
         $pleaseCache = false;
         ob_start('my_cache_function');
     ?>
     <div id="shopping-cart">
         this should be the content I do not want to cache it
     </div>
     <?php
         $output .= ob_get_clean();
         $pleaseCache = true;
         ob_start('my_cache_function');
     ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
     $output .= ob_get_clean();
     ob_end_clean();
     echo $output;
?>
```

Again, not sure this makes a lot of sense... but you have your reasons I presuppose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I gave you and also @Zulakis +1 because you've tried exactly what I've asked for. Unfortunately there was a misunderstood and I think that blue112 solution is the best. Even If I use your solution the shopping cart will not be live If I've get it from the cache file